# How to find first N items with Min values using LINQ

Tags: c#, linq

I am trying to get the first 6 items of `offerList` that have Min `RegularPrice` value and whose `OfferCode` contains "dtv". I tried the following LINQ but it retrieves only one item instead of 6. What am I doing wrong?

```
List<Offer> dtvOffers = offerList.Where(x => 
    (x.ListPrice.CommodityPrice.RegularPrice == offerList.Min(y => 
        y.ListPrice.CommodityPrice.RegularPrice)) && 
    (x.OfferCode.ToLower().Contains("dtv")))
    .Take(6).ToList();
```

Comment: Do you have 6 rows that have the same `RegularPrice` as the `Min(RegularPrice)` ?

Comment: Umm, maybe my query is wrong. basically I want to get any First six items that have min `RegularPrice`. is it the correct way?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Order by `RegularPrice` and take the first 6 rows.

```
offerList.Where(x => x.OfferCode.ToLower().Contains("dtv"))
         .OrderBy(x.ListPrice.CommodityPrice.RegularPrice)
         .Take(6)
         .ToList();
```

This will give you the first six records with the lowest price.

Comment: Perfect solution

Comment: Can't comprehend how this will give more than 6 results.

Comment: @NikhilAgrawal It won't. It will get exactly six records with the lowest prices (assuming there are six records at least in the table).

Comment: @OfirWinegarten: Sorry for my wording. What I wanted to ask is how do your query results are different from what returned by OP's query result.

Comment: @NikhilAgrawal, The OP is filtering so it takes only those that have the same price as the minimun price. Here i'm not filtering on the price, simply sorting it by the price and taking the first 6 records.

Comment: @OfirWinegarten: Exactly. Answer would still be same. Isn't it?

Comment: @NikhilAgrawal totally not. Imagine to have a table with prices 1,1, 2,3. The minimum price is 1, hence the OP query will get only those records with the price of 1. In my case it will take all 4 records. There simply is no filter on the price. Try it.

Answer (score 1):

The only plausible explanation to this is that there are not 6 items which remain after your filter.

The `Take` will take 6 if there are 6 or more items after filter. If not it take what's left. Can also return a blank collection if none left.

Oh and BTW, calculate this line before hand. No use, evaluating for each and every iteration.

```
var min = offerList.Min(y => y.ListPrice.CommodityPrice.RegularPrice);

List<Offer> dtvOffers = offerList.Where(x => 
       (x.ListPrice.CommodityPrice.RegularPrice == min) &&
       (x.OfferCode.ToLower().Contains("dtv")))
    .Take(6).ToList();
```

Comment: maybe my query is wrong. basically I want to get any First six items that have min RegularPrice. is it the correct way?